# How do I remove a Leaflet polyline using marker coords?

Tags: leaflet

I've placed my markers and drawn the polylines between them and it's working great.

I've also given the user the ability to remove a marker using the following function

```js
function hide(marker) {
    map.closePopup();
    map.removeLayer(marker);
}
```

Now, when a marker is removed I'd also like to remove the polyline. I've been doing a lot of searching but haven't come across my specific issue: I'm using pixel coordinates and need to remove the polyline between two markers.

#### markers

```js
var marker1 = L.marker(map.unproject([8706, 7789], map.getMaxZoom()));
var marker2 = L.marker(map.unproject([8302, 5273], map.getMaxZoom()));
var marker3 = L.marker(map.unproject([9303, 7251], map.getMaxZoom()));
```

#### polylines

```js
polyline = L.polyline([
    map.unproject([8706, 7789], map.getMaxZoom()),
    map.unproject([8302, 5273], map.getMaxZoom()),
    map.unproject([9303, 7251], map.getMaxZoom())
]);
```

So when a user removes `marker1`, the polyline disappears between `marker1` and `marker2`, but remains between `marker2` and `marker3`, and so on down the line...
How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the polylines to the markers. And if the marker is removed you can read out the lines and remove them too.

```
marker1 = L.marker([51.498912, -0.122223],{connectedLines: []}).addTo(mymap);
marker2 = L.marker([51.496988, -0.056305],{connectedLines: []}).addTo(mymap);

poly1 = L.polyline([marker1.getLatLng(),marker2.getLatLng()]).addTo(mymap);
marker1.options.connectedLines.push(poly1);
marker2.options.connectedLines.push(poly1);

function removeMarkerLine(e){
  var marker = this;
    if(marker.options && marker.options.connectedLines){
       var lines = marker.options.connectedLines;
       lines.forEach(function(line){
         mymap.removeLayer(line);
       });
    }
  mymap.removeLayer(marker);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/3aukgm7t/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, keep track of which polylines belongs to which two markers, and if one is removed you also remove that one.

Can be easily accomplished using layer groups.